# React-Native: Passing Data to a screen without entering in it

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native to pass data to a component in a previous screen without entering in it. So far I've only seen people using **AsyncStorage** to do that process however I'm having issues on rendering the page after retrieving the data. I have Screen A (which contains the component), Screen B (the screen I'm currently at) and Screen C(the screen I'm navigating at):

Screen A:

```js
export const MainScreen = (props) => {
  const pressing = () => {};

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        <Icon.Button
          name='gear'
          size={60}
          backgroundColor='transparent'
          underlayColor='none'
          onPress={() => {
            pressing();
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.addContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.addBtn}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("FormScreen")}
        >
          <Icon name='plus' size={30} style={styles.addIcon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
        <View style={styles.albaranContainer}>
          <ScrollView>
            <AlbaranComponent />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.navContainer}>
        <View>
          <Icon.Button
            name='bars'
            size={60}
            backgroundColor='transparent'
            underlayColor='none'
            onPress={() => {
              pressing();
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Icon.Button
            name='home'
            size={60}
            backgroundColor='transparent'
            underlayColor='none'
            onPress={() => {
              pressing();
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

The AlbaranComponent code:

```js
export const AlbaranComponent = () => {
  state = {
    albaranes: [
      // [
      // <TouchableOpacity style={styles.albaranTextContainer} onPress={() => {}}>
      //     <View>
      //         <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '5%', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Albarán 1</Text>
      //     </View>
      //     <View>
      //         <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '5%' }}>13/03/2023</Text>
      //         <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '5%' }}>B4XXXXXXX</Text>
      //     </View>
      // </TouchableOpacity>
      // ],
    ],
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@albaran_");
      if (value !== null) {
        this.setState(
          albaranes.push(
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.albaranTextContainer}
              onPress={() => {}}
            >
              <View>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 25,
                    textAlign: "center",
                    marginTop: "5%",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                  }}
                >
                  test1
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View>
                <Text
                  style={{ fontSize: 15, textAlign: "center", marginTop: "5%" }}
                >
                  13/03/2023
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={{ fontSize: 15, textAlign: "center", marginTop: "5%" }}
                >
                  B4XXXXXXX
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  getData();

  if (Object.keys(state.albaranes).length == 0) {
    this.state.albaranes.push([
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 22,
          textAlign: "center",
          marginTop: "5%",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        }}
      >
        No hay albaranes para hoy...
      </Text>,
    ]);
  } else {
    this.state.albaranes.forEach((albaran) => {
      console.log(albaran);
    });
  }

  return <View>{state.albaranes}</View>;
};
```

And Screen B:

```js
export const FormScreen = (props) => {
  const route = useRoute();
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [formModalVisible, setFormModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const storeData = async (value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@albaran_", value);
      console.log("saved!");
      console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem("@albaran_"));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const formCheck = () => {
    if (!text.trim()) {
      setFormModalVisible(true);
    } else {
      storeData(text);
      props.navigation.navigate("AlbaranScreenDetail");
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Modal
        animationType='slide'
        transparent={true}
        visible={formModalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!formModalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>El campo está vacio.</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setFormModalVisible(!formModalVisible)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Aceptar</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        <Icon.Button
          name='gear'
          size={60}
          backgroundColor='transparent'
          underlayColor='none'
          // onPress={() => { pressing() }}
        />
        <Icon.Button
          name='arrow-left'
          size={60}
          backgroundColor='transparent'
          underlayColor='none'
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("MainScreen")}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "bold" }}>Matrícula</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: "#191919", borderRadius: 5 }}
            placeholder='introduzca la matrícula'
            onChangeText={(newText) => setText(newText)}
            defaultValue={text}
          />
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
            <Icon.Button
              name='check'
              size={40}
              color='green'
              backgroundColor='transparent'
              underlayColor='none'
              style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}
              onPress={() => {
                formCheck();
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.navContainer}>
        <View>
          <Icon.Button
            name='bars'
            size={60}
            backgroundColor='transparent'
            underlayColor='none'
            // onPress={() => { pressing() }}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Icon.Button
            name='home'
            size={60}
            backgroundColor='transparent'
            underlayColor='none'
            onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("MainScreen")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

And Screen C which I'm passing into.
Is there a way to pass data from the form of Screen B to a component in Screen A without entering in it and passing solely into Screen C? Are there other better ways to do this process? thanks.

Comment: use state management like  redux

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a state in A and pass it as props to B

in A :

> export const MainScreen = (props) => {   const pressing = () => {};
> const [data, setData]=useState() //

in B, you will be able to use

> props.setData(any data)

so it will update in A.

or you could use react-redux
if you need some data used in many other components

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).